# How to union two different size RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

now I have tow RDDs(array) like this:

1,2

3,4

the second one is like this

5,6,7

8,9,10

now I use rdd1.union(rdd2) and the result is like this:

1,2

3,4

5,6,7

8,9,10

But the result I want is like this:

1,2,0

3,4,0

5,6,7

8,9,10

I just to want to get a array whose rows has the same number of elements,and the new elements is set to 0

I want to know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Map over your first RDD and add an extra 0 element. Then union that with the second RDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost did what you want! The general solution is: you just map the first Rdd to the same structure as the second rdd has. I suggest use tuples and type aliases to make your code a little bit clear. Let's say:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
type X = Double
type Y = Double
type Z = Double
val rdd1: RDD[(X, Y)] = sc.parallelize(List((1,2), (3,4)))
val rdd2: RDD[(X,Y,Z)] = sc.parallelize(List((5,6,7), (8,9,10)))
val result: RDD[(X,Y,Z)] = rdd1
  .map { 
    case(x,y) => (x, y, 0.0)
  }
  .union(rdd2)
```

But if you are not certain about lengths then use arrays, map them into the other arrays with zeros and union after that.

Comment: I vote up the answer because I totally agree with you with mapping the first RDD structure to fit into the second one, but the type aliasing is not necessary.

Comment: You are totally right, it's not neccessary. But i think it's not harmful to mention this trick in context of working with Rdd's. It's pretty quick become very unclear what RDD[(Int, Int, Int)] means if you have a lot of them. Other approach is to use Dataframe.